# How to get last char(s) of a string in C#

Tags: c#, string

Could someone please help me to have a method in C# to return a string as this example:

input string: `21-0001` --> return `1`
input string: `21-0025` --> return `25`
input string: `21-0150` --> return `150`

Thank you very much.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you mind posting some of your code? Thanks.

Comment: If the first part (*"21-"*) is fixed length, try
`var value = "21-0025";
var number = int.Parse(value.Substring(3))`

Comment: Thank you, it works

Answer (score 2):

It could be something like:

```cs
String s = "21-0150";
int result = Int32.Parse(s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf('-') + 1));
```

Comment: What if that value is `21-00150`? Also, I would recommend if going this route, look into `int.TryParse`, can't trust strings :)

Comment: They want it as a string...so need ToString() on the end.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Regexp on System.Text.RegularExpressions namespace.

[Docs link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference?redirectedfrom=MSDN) if you want to know more about the subject.

```cs
var regexp = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"(?<=(-|[0]+))\d+$");

var match = regexp.Match("21-0001");

if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);   
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works

Comment: Counter example: `"21-0150"`, note that `0` is **not in the pattern** you use

Comment: Ops! Thx @DmitryBychenko. I fixed it.

Comment: Now you failed to match `"1234"` in `"21-1234"`

Comment: Fixed... again. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using *regular expression*:

**Code:**

```
 using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

 ...

 string result = Regex.Match(input, "(?:[1-9][0-9]*|0)$").Value;
```

**Pattern explained:** `(?:[1-9][0-9]*|0)$`

```
  (?:            - group start
    [1-9][0-9]*  - one digit in 1..9 rangem followed by digits in 0..9 range
  |              - or
  0              - single 0
  )              - end of group
  $              - end of string
```

**Demo:**

```
string[] tests = new string[] {
  "21-0000", // let's add all zeroes case...
  "21-0001",
  "21-0025",
  "21-0150",
  "21-1234", // ...and no zeroes case
};

string demo = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
  .Select(test => $"{test} --> {Regex.Match(test, "(?:[1-9][0-9]*|0)$").Value}"));

Console.Write(demo);
```

**Outcome:**

```
21-0000 --> 0
21-0001 --> 1
21-0025 --> 25
21-0150 --> 150
21-1234 --> 1234
```

Comment: it works! thank you for details explanation !

Answer (score 1):

You asked for a method that returns the result as a string:

```
    private string MyMethod(string input)
    {
        return input.Split("-").Last().TrimStart('0');
    }
```

It takes the last part of the string after the last "-" and removes the leading zeros.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
static string GetResult(string i) {
    return int.TryParse(i.Substring(i.IndexOf('-') + 1), out int r) ? r.ToString() : string.Empty;
}
```